# Does any one know why my array isnt working

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to call a value from the arrays that the user inputs which element  is to be printed from the arrays, i know that i have an error which says that they do not know what the variables Manipulation Array is and the same with my song and Artist array but when i declare them before me trying to output them it just outputs null values instead of what is in the element in the array

```
package nea2;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NEA2{

    private static Scanner x;
    private static String Scannedpassword3;
    private static String Verifypass;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        File userpass = new File("E:\\NEA\\userpass.txt");
        File Songs = new File("E:\\NEA\\Songs.txt");
        System.out.println("Are you a registered user?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Line = scan.nextLine();
        String scannedusername;
        String scannedpassword;
        String scannedpassword2;
        String scannedusername2;
        String scannedpassword3;

        int outcome = 0;
        int lives = 2;

        if (Line.equals("y") || Line.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter Username");
            scannedusername = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Password");
            scannedpassword = scan.nextLine();

            ConfirmLogin(scannedusername, scannedpassword, userpass);
            outcome++;

        }
        if (Line.equals("n") || Line.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("Create Username");
            scannedusername2 = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Create Password");
            scannedpassword2 = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Verify Password");
            scannedpassword3 = scan.nextLine();
            CreateAccount(scannedusername2, scannedpassword2, scannedpassword3, userpass);
            outcome++;
        }

        ArrayList<String> songs;
        int points = 0;
        //Spelt ManipulationArray incorrectly (ManipluationArray)


        Scanner start = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yes;
        System.out.println("Are you ready?(yes/no)");
        yes = start.nextLine();
        switch (yes) {
            case "no":
                System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Say yes to start the quiz.");
                System.exit(1);
            case "yes":
                System.out.println("Quiz starting, be ready");
                outcome++;
                //Incorrect Range Check
                if (outcome > 1)
                    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 0 and 19");
                int input1 = scan.nextInt();
                                System.out.println(ManipulationArray[20]+","+ArtistArray[20]);

                                System.out.println("Please enter your guess");
                                String SongGuess=scan.nextLine();
                                if (SongGuess.equals(SongArray[input1])) {
                                    System.out.println("Correct,you have gained 3 points" + points+3);

                //You don't need to define a new Scanner every time you wish to get an input from the user
                //You don't need the to define a variables datatype again (you had String Num here which was already defined as a String previously)

                                Scanner inputs = new Scanner(System.in);
                String Num = scan.nextLine();
                //Wrong scanner method
                int input = scan.nextInt();
                //Incorrect concatenation attempt

                        String SongArray[] = new String[20];
                SongArray[0] = "Me And My Guitar";
                SongArray[1] = "Drowning";
                SongArray[2] = "DNA";
                SongArray[3] = "The Box";
                SongArray[4] = "Roxxane";
                SongArray[5] = "Dance Monkey";
                SongArray[6] = "Dior";
                SongArray[7] = "Girls Like You";
                SongArray[8] = "Shape Of You";
                SongArray[9] = "God's Plan";
                SongArray[10] = "Ballin'";
                SongArray[11] = "Blueberry Faygo";
                SongArray[12] = "Moonlight";
                SongArray[13] = "Sad!";
                SongArray[14] = "Believer";
                SongArray[15] = "Mask Off";
                SongArray[16] = "iSpy";
                SongArray[17] = "Congratulations";
                SongArray[18] = "Happpier";
                SongArray[19] = "Godzilla";


                        String ArtistArray[] = new String[20];
                ArtistArray[0] = "A Boogie Wit Da Hoodie";
                ArtistArray[1] = "A Boogie Wit Da Hoodie";
                ArtistArray[2] = "Kendrick Lamar";
                ArtistArray[3] = "Roddy Rich";
                ArtistArray[4] = "Arizona Zervas";
                ArtistArray[5] = "Tones and I";
                ArtistArray[6] = "Pop Smoke";
                ArtistArray[7] = "Maroon 5";
                ArtistArray[8] = "Ed Sheeran";
                ArtistArray[9] = "Drake";
                ArtistArray[10] = "Mustard";
                ArtistArray[11] = "Lil Mosey";
                ArtistArray[12] = "xxxtentaction";
                ArtistArray[13] = "xxxtentaction";
                ArtistArray[14] = "Imagine Dragons";
                ArtistArray[15] = "Future";
                ArtistArray[16] = "Kyle";
                ArtistArray[17] = "Post Malone";
                ArtistArray[18] = "Marshmello";
                ArtistArray[19] = "Eminem";

                                String ManipulationArray[] = new String[20];
                ManipulationArray[0] = "M* A** M* G*****";
                ManipulationArray[1] = "D*******";
                ManipulationArray[2] = "D**";
                ManipulationArray[3] = "T** B**";
                ManipulationArray[4] = "R******";
                ManipulationArray[5] = "D**** M*****";
                ManipulationArray[6] = "D***";
                ManipulationArray[7] = "G**** L*** Y**";
                ManipulationArray[8] = "S**** O* Y**";
                ManipulationArray[9] = "G**** P***";
                ManipulationArray[10] = "B******";
                ManipulationArray[11] = "B******** F****";
                ManipulationArray[12] = "M********";
                ManipulationArray[13] = "S***";
                ManipulationArray[14] = "B*******";
                ManipulationArray[15] = "M**** O**";
                ManipulationArray[16] = "i***";
                ManipulationArray[17] = "C**************";
                ManipulationArray[18] = "H******";
                ManipulationArray[19] = "G*******";




        }
    }
        }

    public static void ConfirmLogin(String scannedusername, String scannedpassword, File userpass) throws FileNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            x = new Scanner(userpass).useDelimiter(",");
            int outcome = 0;

            while (x.hasNext()) {
                final String lineFromFile = x.nextLine();
                if (lineFromFile.equals(scannedusername + "," + scannedpassword)) {
                    outcome = outcome + 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (outcome > 0) {
                System.out.println("Login Successful");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Username or Password is incorrect");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error file not found");
        }
    }

    public static void CreateAccount(String username2, String scannedpassword2, String scannedpassword3, File userpass) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Verifypass = scannedpassword2;

        if (Verifypass.equals(scannedpassword3)) {
            System.out.println("Account Creation complete");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            FileWriter fWriter;
            BufferedWriter writer;

            try {

                fWriter = new FileWriter(userpass, true);
                writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                writer.write(username2 + "," + scannedpassword2);
                writer.newLine();
                writer.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error creating account, Bare with us.");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Passwords do not match");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: post those errors in proper format

Comment: What is the proper format?

Comment: check: 1. System.out.println(ManipulationArray[20]+","+ArtistArray[20]); Your arraysize is 20 so you have start counting by 0. I think you mean: ManipulationArray[input1] where input1 has to between 0 and 19. 2. You have to fill the arrays before you read from them

Comment: You will get better feedback if you post a more minimal code example, along with error messages in your post (as @AbhinavChauhan said)